# Python text file not reading

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a text file named `test.text` which has a few lines of plain text. Then I wrote

```py
with open("test.txt") as f: 
    text = f.read() 
    print(text)
```

in a separate file named `filetest.py`

When the code is executed it runs but it returns an empty result, i.e. it doesn't show the output. Console simply shows: $. Why is it not displaying the contents of the file?

Comment: Is the code indented? I.e. the lines `f.read()` and `print(text)` are they inward, with respect to the first line?

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you, since you were missing a closing `"`. If this doesn't work, the file may not exist. Try putting in it' full path

Comment: IndentationError & missing "  Use an absolute path .- you are not in the folder you think you operate on.

Comment: I have used correct formatting and indentation. It doesn't show the text from test.txt. I am using VS code for this

Comment: @Jeg, edit your question and fix the problems with your example. Once you've fixed the syntax errors in your code, it _should_ work fine. If it doesn't, you're doing something wrong that you haven't mentioned -- like not having test.txt in the working directory. You can check the working directory using [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Comment: correct- its working now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fix the "test.txt" string. Also use ident and read only.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f: 
    text = f.read() 
    print(text)
```

Comment: My bad = I wrote it correctly but accidentally left out the string here. It still doesn't show an output. Adding "r" doesn't work either, still an empty output

Comment: Where is test.txt file located>?

Comment: its in a folder, same folder as filetest.py. I am using VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Might be an obvious oversight, but are you sure you're file name is correct? Even one letter difference, or uppercase vs lowercase has the potential to break things.

I ask because your description has `test.text`, but your code shows your trying to read `test.txt`.

Also, you might look into using the [`os`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_file_methods.htm) module. It makes it a bit easier for the computer to access your file with OS specific nuances.

---

### Try This:

```py
import os

myFile = os.path.abspath("/path/to/text.txt")

with open(myFile, "r") as file:
    contents = file.read()

print(contents)
```

Comment: yes it is correct. I think there's an issue with where my file is located? Does it have to be in the text editor?

Comment: text editor? No, but you do need to make sure you're accessing the correct file in the right directory. If you are executing your script from one directory but accessing the file in another, you are probably gonna run into problems. 

I added an example in my answer for you to look at